# Does each transaction have its own gas price in NEAR?

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

In the near indexer, only the gas price of blocks and action_receipts are available. Does NEAR have a gas price for every transaction like ETH?
[near-indexer-for-explorer-db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NqSm.png)
[ETH transaction example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i0sZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Each transaction costs gas, and that transaction will always costs the same *units* of gas. The *price* of gas units varies, however.

> Gas units: internally, transaction fees are not calculated directly in
> NEAR tokens, but instead go through an in-between phase of "gas
> units". The benefit of gas units is that they are deterministic – the
> same transaction will always cost the same number of gas units.
>
> Gas price: gas units are then multiplied by a gas price to determine
> how much to charge users. This price is automatically recalculated
> each block depending on network demand (if previous block is more than
> half full the price goes up, otherwise it goes down, and it won't
> change by more than 1% each block), and bottoms out at a price that's
> configured by the network, currently 100 million yoctoNEAR.

https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/gas